# incorrect scale `plotly` 3D surface

Tags: r, dataframe, 3d, plotly, surface

I have a 3D surface but the scale seems incorrect.

[image]

Its:

```r
grid.df
         X       Y   rkgls
1   264250 6247750    9.12
2   264750 6247750    9.25
3   265250 6247750    9.53
4   265750 6247750    9.99
5   266250 6247750   10.65
etc.
```

with:

```r
#- to matrix
grid.df_matrix <- acast(grid.df, X~Y, value.var="rkgls")
#- get the values for the x and y columns: this might be where I'm going wrong
y <- x <- as.numeric(rownames(grid.df_matrix))
#- plot
fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~grid.df_matrix, x= x, y=y, colors = rainbow(100), 
                           type = "surface") %>%
  layout(
    scene=list(
    xaxis=list(title='x (m)'),
    yaxis=list(title='y (m)'),
    zaxis=list(title='Elevation (m)')))

fig
```

The area is 500*500m at 1680rows in the `data.frame` with a z (rkgls) difference of ~100m.
Neither the scale nor the axis values seems correct.

Have I overlooked something basic and obvious to render the scale and axis values correctly?

Comment: `as.numeric(rownames(grid.df_matrix))` gives you the correct value for X, but the values for Y should be `as.numeric(colnames(grid.df_matrix))`

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. The x and y axis now have the correct labels but the z still seems exaggerated. The scale seems _off_ somehow.

Comment: of course the z axis is exaggerated - the range of z values is about 200 times smaller than the range of the other two variables. If it wasn't exaggerated, your whole 3d plot would look essentially like a completely flat plane.